# use boost::is_upper properly

Tags: c++, boost

How can I know whether a string contains a upper case or not?

for a string `token`,

```
for (std::string::iterator tokenIter = token.begin(); tokenIter != token.end(); tokenIter++) {
    return boost::all(*tokenIter, boost::is_upper(locale))

}
```

but it seems weird. Is there any elegent way to do this?

Comment: Remove the if and just `return boost::all ....`.

Comment: please read the code. `boost::all()` is used on every single character of target string token. Once find any upper case, it'll return true.

Comment: @Tilney Ah, okay. That isn't what your code is doing, and that made it unclear to me what you were really after. `boost::all` doesn't really make sense on a single character, and you're unconditionally returning a value, even if it's false. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: you can call `boost::all` on a single character string... Sorry, I didn't compile that code before. Just a heuristic thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1 = "hello";
    cout << std::boolalpha << std::any_of(str1.begin(), str1.end(), boost::is_upper()) << endl; //false

    string str2 = "Hello";
    cout << std::boolalpha << std::any_of(str2.begin(), str2.end(), boost::is_upper()) << endl; //true

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't have C++11, you can use `boost::any_of` instead.

Comment: Is it possible that we can use boost classification methods `is_upper` etc. on a single character as what we can do in java `Character.isUpperCase(char)`? Source code of boost is really hard to understand...

Comment: Use isupper(), refer this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/

Comment: Problem is I want to use it with Russian and German which contains non-ASCII character. `wstring` is disapproved. I am trying to figure out whether can do this with out a third-party lib(such as ICU) or not.

Comment: @Tilney, Take a look at boost::locale. std::string grussen = "grüßEN"; std::cout   <<"Upper "<< boost::locale::to_upper(grussen) << std::endl

Comment: I'm working with boost1.46.1, which doesn't support local.. By the way, boost::locale is based on ICU. Seems like I have to decode utf-8 on my own. Thanks for everything!